# How to get PHP to do the same thing my ColdFusion does

Tags: php

For those of you who have seen my previous questions, here is the problem. I am converting some ColdFusion into PHP. Here is the ColdFusion that works great.

```
 <cfset ColCount = 0>
        <cfloop query="getArt">
            <cfset ColCount = ColCount + 1>
            <cfif ColCount is 1>
                <div id="clear"></div>
            </cfif>
            <div id="thumb" onClick="window.location='gallery_detail.cfm?AID=#AID#';" title="Enlarge">
                <div id="thumb_container">
                    <a href="gallery_detail.cfm?AID=#AID#" ><img src="/#ThumbFilePath#" alt="Enlarge" border="0"></a>
                    <div id="name_spacer"></div>
                    <div id="thumbdesc">
                        #Title#
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <cfif ColCount LT 4></cfif>
            <cfif ColCount is 4>
                <cfset ColCount = 0>
            </cfif>
        </cfloop>
```

Here is the PHP that I am trying to get to do the same thing the ColdFusion does.

```
<?php  
$dbname = 'pdartist2';  
$table = 'artwork';  
// query  
$result = mysql_query("SELECT AID, ThumbFilePath, Title, DisplayOrder FROM artwork    where SCID = '$SCID' ") or die(mysql_error());  
while($row = mysql_fetch_row($result))  
{  
$colCount = 0;  
foreach($row as $cell) {  
  $colCount++;  
  if ColCount is 1
  echo "<div id="clear"></div>";
  echo "<div id="thumb" onClick="window.location='gallery_detail.php?AID=$AID';" title="Enlarge">";
      echo "<div id="thumb_container">";
          <a href="gallery_detail.php?AID=$AID" ><img src="/$ThumbFilePath" alt="Enlarge" border="0"></a>
      echo "<div id="name_spacer"></div>";
      echo "<div id="thumbdesc">";
              $Title
      echo "</div>";
      echo "</div>";
      echo "</div>";

    }  
}  
 mysql_free_result($result);  

?>
```

I know that this somewhat rough, but you get the idea. Obviously, ColdFusion and PHP handle HTML and SQL quite differently. I wouldn't make the change unless I had too, alas I do.

Comment: Have you considered reading the [Language Reference](http://es.php.net/manual/en/langref.php) chapter in the PHP manual? At least the first sections. It's silly to waste everybody's time, including yours, just to learn the basic PHP operators as they show up in your code.

Comment: I told you under your last question and I tell you now: before coming here crying for things not working, please review your php syntax first! Also, enable error reporting, don't let it cry unseen

Comment: You're too funny Damien! We each have our own gifts buddy. It just so happens that code is not one of mine. Nonetheless, I will do my best not to bother you-all with stupidness.

Comment: It's more for you than for the others. If you know the right syntax, then you work out a big part of the problems you're having so far. Spend some hours in learning the syntax and you'll save 10 times more hours in trying to figure out (or writing to SO) why things don't work as espected. Also, enabling errors is another time saver :)

Comment: @theolddog Which editor are you using to write code? If one is available, I'd suggest using a PHP validator to check where the errors in your code are, as you code. In my editor, a quick command + shift + v will tell me if there are any holes in the code I've written. Having something say `unexpected T_ECHOblahblah at line 172` is extremely useful. Once you become familiar with errors, you'll find debugging things like this very easy.

Comment: Steve, I use Dreamweaver, but I will check into a PHP validator, I think Dreamweaver has this. PS I see on your profile you like visual art. Take a look at my work, let me know what you think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Line 11:

`if ColCount is 1` should be `if( $colCount > 0 )`

Line 12 and several below as well:
`echo "<div id=\"clear\"></div>";` - The " characters need to be escaped here. Alternatively, produce the string this way: `echo '<div id="clear"></div>';`

Line 15 and 18 lack an output method.

You should consider placing less presentation in a logic file.

Edit: Let me elaborate on that. In this case, aside from having your syntax wrong, you're also bypassing good practice by placing so much presentation data directly into a logic file. What you could do instead is place your logic into gallery.php or something, then in a php template file, use that logic. For example (This won't work for you, exactly as it is):

```
<?php
  // Here is our logic
  $dbname = 'pdartist2';
  $table = 'artwork';
  // query
  $result = mysql_query("SELECT AID, ThumbFilePath, Title, DisplayOrder FROM artwork    where SCID = '$SCID' ") or die(mysql_error());
  $row = mysql_fetch_row($result);

  $colCount = 0;
?>

<!-- Here is the view -->
<?php foreach($row as $cell): ?>
  <div id="clear"></div>
  <div id="thumb" onClick="window.location="gallery_detail.php?AID=<?php echo $AID ?>"" title="Enlarge">
    <div id="thumb_container">
      <a href="gallery_detail.php?AID=<?php echo $AID ?>" ><img src="/$ThumbFilePath" alt="Enlarge" border="0"></a>
      <div id="name_spacer"></div>
      <div id="thumbdesc"><?php echo $Title ?></div>
    </div>
  </div>
 <?php endforeach ?>
```

Comment: I appreciate your help Steve. I am not a full time geek like some of the folks here. I am a full time portrait artist, unfortunately I enjoy working on my own website, LOL. However, it gives me headaches at times. My question for you is; how would I apply the <?php foreach to each result?

Comment: @Theolddog That's a good question. I excluded the while loop from your code for convenience, but I should have expected that to be confusing. I believe you'd use the same code you had, but slightly different to accomodate the logic/view architecture: `<?php while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)): ?> ##foreach loop is nested here## <?php endwhile ?>`

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php  
$dbname = 'pdartist2';  
$table = 'artwork';  
// query  
$result = mysql_query("SELECT AID, ThumbFilePath, Title, DisplayOrder FROM artwork    where SCID = '$SCID' ") or die(mysql_error());  
$colCount = 0;   
while($cell = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {      
    $colCount++;  
    if($colCount > 0) {
        echo '<div id="clear"></div>';
    }
    echo '<div id="thumb" onClick="window.location=\'gallery_detail.cfm?AID='.$cell['AID'].'\';" title="Enlarge">
                <div id="thumb_container">
                    <a href="gallery_detail.cfm?AID='.$cell['AID'].'" ><img src="/'.$cell['ThumbFilePath'].'" alt="Enlarge" border="0"></a>
                    <div id="name_spacer"></div>
                    <div id="thumbdesc">
                        '.$cell['Title'].'
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>';

    if($colCount == 4) $colCount = 0;
}  

?>
```

here you go

**please consider to learn PHP when you will find next PHP problem.**

Comment: I am working on learning PHP Peter. However, Godaddy put the pressure on me to switch from Cold Fusion to PHP by the end of next month. And I have so many other things I need to do :-( Bye the way, this code get an error, unexpected $end.